Unable to access Cloudflare D1 database in a Nuxt 3 API route when deployed to Cloudflare Pages
Project is built in Nuxt 3 and is being deployed to Pages via GitHub integration.
Cloudflare Dashboard was used to create a binding in the Pages project to the D1 database using variable "DB".
I have been unable to access this binding in an API route when the app is deployed.
'Database connection is not configured.' is the error received - which makes me think the binding isn't properly being accessed. I haven't been able to find consistent documentation on the chain of environment variables one must use in this context (accessing a D1 binding in Nuxt on Pages).
In the API route (/server/api/database.js):
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {

    // access the database
    const db = event.context.cloudflare.env.DB;

    if (!db) {
      throw new Error('Database connection is not configured.');
    }

...

Local development is working... I installed wrangler and helper module nitro-cloudflare-dev and have the following wrangler.toml file:
[[d1_databases]]
binding = "DB"
database_name = "prod-example"
database_id = "813210b5-f217-4eaa-ae5d-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
preview_database_id = "DB"

My reading:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/framework-guides/deploy-a-nuxt-site/#use-bindings-in-your-nuxt-application

https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/functions/bindings/#d1-databases

https://developers.cloudflare.com/d1/build-with-d1/local-development/#develop-locally-with-pages



This was user error. Cloudflare has updated the UI for its Pages settings - the environment (production/preview) dropdown scrolls out of view when accessing the binding setting. My binding was configured correctly, it had just never been established for the preview environment.
Cloudflare Pages Settings Environment Setting Location
